# Быстрый перебор переменных

Tags: python

У меня есть 9 переменных:

```
p_1 = int(input())
p_2 = int(input())
P_3 = int(input())
p_4 = int(input())
p_5 = int(input())
p_6 = int(input())
p_7 = int(input())
p_8 = int(input())
p_9 = int(input())
```

В следующим шаге мне нужно перебрать все 9 переменных, как это сделать быстро(с помощью цикла for in)?

Comment: >  помощью цикла for in - почему бы и нет? Но если вам нужна действительно высокая скорость - лучше выбрать какой-нибудь низкоруровневый (*или хотя-бы компилируемый*) ЯП. Но опять же зависит от сложности перебора. Если вам просто переменные сравнить на больше/меньше - разницы вы не увидите.

Comment: Как только появляется необходимость в переменных с номерами - это сигнал, что нужно использовать список.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
all_p = [int(input()) for _ in range(9)]

for p in all_p:
    # Тут делаете то, что вам нужно с переменной "p"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p_1 = int(input())
p_2 = int(input())
P_3 = int(input())
p_4 = int(input())
p_5 = int(input())
p_6 = int(input())
p_7 = int(input())
p_8 = int(input())
p_9 = int(input())

for var in [value for key, value in locals().items() if key.startswith('p_')]:
  print(var)
```